# Exception for unexpected return value from another method

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am looking for a BCL exception type to throw in case of unexpected return value from a call to another method.

I would name it somehow like `UnexpectedReturnValueException`, but obviously .NET Framework does not have anything like this.

Here is an example of code to illustrate:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private int savedMonth;

    private ISomeOtherClass other;

    public void DoSomething(int month, string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }

        if (!value.StartsWith("A"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value should always start with an 'A'", "value");
        }

        if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("month", "Month should be in range of 1 to 12");
        }

        if (savedMonth == month)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Provided month should be different from saved month");
        }

        var result = other.GetResult();

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new ??? // What should I throw here?
        }

        // do other work here

    }
}

public interface ISomeOtherClass
{
    SomeOtherClassReturnValue GetResult();
}

public class SomeOtherClassReturnValue
{
}
```

### Important:

As per my understanding based on MSDN the following exceptions are not suitable here:

- `ArgumentException` - The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments **provided to a method** is not valid.
- `ArgumentNullException` - The exception that is thrown when a null reference is **passed to a method** that does not accept it as a valid argument.
- `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` - The exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values **as defined by the invoked method**.
- `InvalidOperationException` - The exception that is thrown when a method call is **invalid for the object's current state**.

Comment: If `other.GetResult()` is written in such a way that it can return null, how is that unexpected?

Comment: Apparently, this scenario is not common enough to warrant a built-in exception type. You can just create your own exception type and throw that.

Comment: @Szymon, as far `SomeClass` is just using `other`, it can provide its expectation in form of thrown exception. As an example, let's suppose the `other` is a Guid generator returning a `string`. In this case we have all rights to expect the value not to be null. And we express it in code by checking the return value and throwing `UnexpectedResultException` rather than getting `NullReferenceException` when using this value or `ArgumentNullException` when trying to add it to dictionary, for example.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, this is correct, my own exception type is always an option. However I just have a feeling, that there should be something out there which is considered the 'best practice' for this situation :)

Comment: Best practice is to avoid using exception whenever possible.

Comment: If other.GetResult(); is expected to return null values as a normal behavior, they you should deal with it within the natural flow of the program and not with an Exception.
This is also true to your inputs tests. I would recommend having a bool / string return value and not throwing exceptions.
You can read more about it on the following link to MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I would agree, that exception should be used to describe exceptional situations and violation of assumptions. In this particular case `other.GetResult()` is not expected to return `null` and I am trying to enforce this assumption by throwing a meaningful exception.

Comment: Well in that case, you can either throw a general exception with a custom message, or create a specific exception that inherits from Exception and throw that.

Answer (score 2):

If null value is *exceptional* and therefore exception is needed, best built-in type is `InvalidOperationException`.

As author states, error is not caused directly from method parameters, therefore no any Argument* -Exception is suitable for this case.

`SomeClass` has `ISomeOtherClass other` as a private member in the class and method caller cannot have any visibility to it. `ISomeOtherClass`-dependency is then part of object's internal state. As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception) states:

> InvalidOperationException is thrown when a method call is invalid for
>   the object's current state.
>
> InvalidOperationException is used in cases when the failure to invoke
>   a method is caused by reasons other than invalid arguments.